# Can you print a Flowdocument Table in WPF with repeatable table column headers

Tags: wpf, printing, flowdocument

How can you print a Flowdocument Table in WPF with repeatable table column headers?

I have seen this one [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PimpedDocumentPaginator.aspx] and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with the referenced CodeProject, but it ALMOST works, and I have had success with the following changes:

In GetPage, just delete the four lines that reference the Console.

In the Definition class add

```
public static Size Subtract( Size s1, Size s2 )
{
    return new Size( s1.Width - s2.Width, s1.Height - s2.Height );
}
```

and change ContentSize get to

```
    return Subtract( PageSize, new Size(
        Margins.Left + Margins.Right,
        Margins.Top + Margins.Bottom + HeaderHeight + FooterHeight) );
```

Then, in your own code, something like this to call it on a button click: -- I didn't like his class name :)

```
PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog( );
printDialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
if ( true == printDialog.ShowDialog( ) )
{

  MyPaginator.Definition d = new MyPaginator.Definition
    {
        Header = ( c, b, n ) => c.DrawRectangle( Brushes.Black, null, b ),
        Margins = new Thickness( 48 ), // 1/2 inch all around
        PageSize = new Size( flowDocument.PageWidth, flowDocument.PageHeight ),
    };
  DocumentPaginator s = new MyPaginator( flowDocument, d );
  printDialog.PrintDocument( s, "Print Job Title" );
}
```

In my case, I didn't need a Footer, but that Header delegate (or something like it) is a must.  The Margins and PageSize will default, but I wanted different values.

Finally, I found that I needed to add `KeepTogether = true` to my Paragraph definitions for my TableCells.

Comment: I was also losing my TextAlignment settings between View and Print:  A suggestion at this link fixed me up:  [FlowDocument Text Alignment](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a8a7b9af-2487-4041-af4d-68752d249b2b/) - and reduced my code.

Comment: Unfortunately this does nothing at all. I guessed to add `RepeatTableHeaders = true` to the `Definition` but nothing gets repeated in my table.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to paginate the document yourself, in the same fashion that you would word wrap a paragraph of text.  Checking to see if the next row will fit, pagebreaking if not, starting each page off with the table header, and continuing to append table rows until the page is full.

Unfortunately none of the paginators does this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:[WPF Reports](http://wpfreports.codeplex.com/)
It supports header/footer and has some nice feature. 
Good luck